# What can I do with unused cheque book?

Tags: canada, banking, check, checking-account

I will be switching all my accounts from Bank A to Bank B within the next few weeks. A few months ago, I purchased a cheque book for my Bank A checking account. It contains 50 cheques (all unused).

Is there something I can do with these cheques (like returning them to the bank) to salvage some of the amount paid to obtain the chequebook?

Comment: This is something that is likely to be country-specific and possibly bank-specific as well, and since you choose not to specify either, it is hard to say for sure. But most likely, returning them to the bank is not going to get you a refund of the money you paid to buy the cheques. Unless the bank is going to assign the same account number to someone else right away, the cheques are useless to the bank. If they have been pre-printed with your name and/or address (common in the US), they are even more useless to the bank unless it can find a customer with the same name and/or address as you.

Comment: You can shred the checks and use them to line a bird cage or a cat's litter box. You could light them on fire to produce supplemental heat for your home in the winter. I think that's about all they are good for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the US and Canada, you would typically pay between US$12 to 25 for an initial order of 250 checks, in 5 books of 50 each. This includes the register and check book case. The checks have your name, your address, unique bank account number and bank routing number on each check. The bank will **NOT** refund your money for any unused checks.

In fact, you need to **shred or otherwise destroy the old checks** from Bank A as soon as you have closed out the account and confirmed that the transfer to Bank B is complete. The old checks are a potential risk, should anyone with fraudulent intent find or take them from you.

Some checkbook cases are worth keeping and re-using. You can do that with the new checks, as the sizes are standardized.